# Feedback first ever brand design

Tags: critique, branding

[UPDATE]
I revised the design based on your feedback, which was really helpful, thank you!

[image]

---

I'm a student and have to gather feedback for my assignment on my brand design. Any feedback is helpful, especially because I've never done graphic design before. The design is for a mockup brand which helps empower women through business coaching.

[image]

Comment: Hey Arin. Please update your post to follow our [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682)

Comment: I like the business cards. Try doing something with that swirly texture.

Answer (score 0):

**Please realize this is all merely my *opinion* as a designer and you *asked* for opinions.** I am *not specifically trying* to be negative, although my opinions may not be what you *want* to read. My goal is to provide an open and honest *opinion* of what I see based upon my experience. My opinions are **not** always correct or inline with the opinions of others. I can be, and often am, simply wrong.

In short, please read this understanding it's posted from the sole desire to **help** you improve this brand.

---

I *like* the color palette. It's feminine but strong. Good choices!

---

Overall.....

- For a brand which is meant to convey "feminine empowerment" it is *very* strong on "feminine" but very weak on "empowerment".
- The mark is light and sort of "wispy" in perception. This goes a long way to conveying "feminine" for many viewers. Although, this can be a bit cliché. There's *nothing* stating a "feminine brand" needs to be less impactful and "delicate." (...or use pink.)
- The color palette is strong and conveys empowerment.
- Unfortunately, the light nature of the readable items outweighs the color choices and, in my opinion, "empowerment" isn't conveyed much, if at all.

---

Regarding typeface choices...

- A mono-spaced font for headlines *won't* work. There will (hopefully) be myriad uses for the branding. Insisting on a mono-spaced font for headlines does nothing but ensure that, in some cases, headlines will be too long, break poorly, and not fit a space allotted.

  - Headlines can often entail minor kerning and word spacing adjustments to improve readability. A mono-spaced font simply makes all that a headache.
  - In addition, the general public may perceive monospacing as unfriendly or overly cold and digital. That's typically *not* a desired impression for a brand.
- Granville light ... It's a nice looking typeface. However, for *me*, the contrast is too high.

  - The weight variation between the thick and thin glyph strokes is too extreme. At smaller sizes thin glyphs may get "lost" when reading making legibility a challenge.
  - At larger sizes, the thick strokes *may* overwhelm a paragraph visually. Causing it to be perceived as "heavier" than other, more important, elements within a layout. Essentially, a high contrast body typeface can make layout balance a challenge.
- I don't know why you'd designate a script font. Doing so merely encourages its use... which, to me, is a mistake.

---

Regarding the graphic treatment of the F.....

- I perceive a shadowy, nondescript, figure standing behind type. Almost "looming".
- The graphic is exceptionally similar to a "user" icon, which is very prevalent and will outweigh any other perception you wish to covey with the figure.
- The "half diamond" and "arrow" you point out.. well.. I don't think *anyone* will *ever* see those elements, even subconsciously due to the perception of a "user icon".

Unfortunately, one must account for what is *already* prevalent and overused to the public. It's a nice figure, it is simply too similar to a user icon in my opinion.

Combine the user icon perception with a monospaced typeface, and I feel the brand just "pushes" the sense of cold, digital, computer related. I would assume the *desired* impression would convey more things such as friendly, helpful, mentoring, support, coaching, etc.

---

Regarding the "stacked" version....

*Just a pet peeve of mine*... Graphic treatment of a glyph that spans more than one line and is supposed to be read *multiple times* to make sense of what the reader is seeing.

Would you place a single big F at the beginning of both lines and expect viewers to read that F twice? If not, then why is the graphic "F" being used in this manner?

It works against the purpose of being easily read and recognized:

- Its a graphic treatment for a glyph which asks the viewer to decipher or figure out what glyph it's meant to be. (Granted, this is *not* difficult in this instance.)
- It's used repeatedly, asking the viewer to decipher when the "glyph" is supposed to be repeatedly read. Is it supposed to read "emme ortune", "Femme ortune", "emme Fortune", "Femme Fortune"? (Again, this is *not* difficult in this specific brand design, but it is something to consider long before going down such a design path.)

---

The business card....

Although I *like* the graphic pattern you've chosen, unfortunately the weight of the lines in the pattern are far too similar to the stroke weight of the type sitting on top the pattern.

This causes visual confusion because **all** the lines appear the same weight and importance. It tends to cause an "uneasy feeling" because the eye just bounces everywhere.. as if you are shaking your head and trying to read something at the same time.

In addition, the pattern almost conveys a "retro subway tile" atmosphere -  very mid-century modern, almost dating the design (and company).

Viewers may not know *why* they dislike the card... but they will surely dislike it. You *may* be able to mitigate this by making the pattern elements much smaller so its lines are not as prominent, I'm uncertain.

---

I'm hesitant to be so blunt, but... *nothing* about this design would make me believe this is for a brand whose goal is to **help** *anyone* do *anything*. There's no connotation of friendliness, support, human interaction, personal service, coaching, mentoring, helpfulness, etc. *Nothing* abut the design seems inviting or encouraging. The mark and type choices, to me, are overall very cold digital and non-specific -- as if it's for a company that merely gathers user data through automated digital services.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth feedback. To improve, I was thinking of how to add in more of that helpfulness component. Do you think different font choices would help enough, or would a graphic element help more?

Answer (score 0):

I am a mixed-skill designer -- more skilled at math and technical stuff than art -- and consider my artsy design skills crude at best. I'm good enough to copy and alter quality work and even make it better, but I can almost never "roll my own from scratch" successfully.  I say all this just to explain my following comment is coming from a guy who is a mediocre designer, so you have some context.

My primary comment is that I *never have succeeded at making a uniform thickness stroke look good on anything*.  Your hand-crafted capital 'F' letter forms are uniform thickness -- nothing more than lines with a continuous width stroke. In my humble opinion, trying to pull off a great design with continuous-width strokes is like trying to ski the black diamond on your first day. I can't do it even after decades of trying -- I'm not sure its even possible.

Scott commented that your design feels cold and calculated instead of "helpful". I agree. I chalk a lot of it up to the mono-spaced font combined with the continuous-width strokes. The lack of stroke thickness variation is a missed opportunity for depth and character.

There is a time-element problem here. If you try to hand-craft your own letter forms (as opposed to buying an awesome licensed font), you're going to have to spend the tedious time required to make your letter shape rock. If you've got the budget and time for it and the skill, do it! The greatest brands, movie titles, and everything are typically built with completely custom letter forms!  But don't think you can draw a line and then put a stroke on it and be done. *I've never seen that work. Your milage may vary.*